# Which airport is open more in late December, early January. Denver or Chicago?

Tags: airports, chicago, denver

My google foo is failing me.

I am booking travel in late December, early January and need to change planes.  I have two reasonable options, Denver and Chicago.  Prices/times are similar.  Which closes more frequently in those months?

Comment: Your best bet is probably on-time or cancellation statistics.  Unfortunately the government statistics are broken down by airline, and I couldn't immediately find a source that aggregates all flights to/from a given airport.

Comment: Both can be hit hard by snow and associated delays but in my experience Chicago is more prone to "wipe out" events that shuts the whole airport down.
Still, these everts are rare enough that statistics won't help you much. Just book whatever is the best itinerary and/or price. In this case optimizing around weather has no clear winner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your actual concern is missing a connecting flight, since it's quite unusual for an airport to shut down completely: usually they keep operating, just at lower capacity.

If so, you're probably better off with **Denver**, since on average it has both fewer delays for arriving flights and shorter delays for departing flights than Chicago O'Hare.

https://www.visualcapitalist.com/visualizing-the-u-s-airports-with-the-worst-flight-delays/

Comment: I think you're missing "arrivals" and "departures" in your second sentence?